# Want to pass single variable from view to the same template in django

Tags: jquery, python, django

I want to pass the one variable from the view to the templates.

But i am using that template for another view

i am using that template for this view

```
def poll(request):
    questions = PollQuestion.objects.all()
    return render(request,'poll/poll.html',{'questions':questions})
```

i want to use same template for

```
def score(request):
    score1=UserProfile.objects.all()
    print score1
    print type(score1)

    return render(request, 'poll/poll.html',{'score1': score1})
```

i have model.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User) 
    score = models.IntegerField(max_length = 50, blank = True,null = True)
```

i want to get that score to jquery variable in poll.html and want to store again to database after doing modification to that score.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two questions in my opinion:

1. how two views function use one html template
2. one page not only show the score but also make change in database after modification.

for solve the first, you can try:

```
{% if score1 %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

do the same thing to the `questions`; put the corresponding code in the `...`

for solve the second, you can try below in the views.py:

```
if request.METHOD == 'GET':
    ...
    # show score
    ...
elif reqeust.METHOD == 'POST':
    ...
    # store to database
    ...
```

do some need modification to the html template if you want use `request.METHOD` to differ.

Comment: Exaclly,,,,,,,,,,,, These are my questions

Comment: Its not even going to the if loop i.e.  <script>{% if score1 %}
    alert("hi")
{% endif %}  </script>

Comment: let me see your whole poll.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is problem ? You know the answer and you are doing it.

If you are looking for How to pass the value and use in jquery then,

You have already solved the problem that is passing the the value to view.

To use inside javascript

```
var score1 = {{score1}}
```

Now you can use score1 as variable in jquery

**How to post data back to server**

Here are steps, 
I am assuming you are using ajax call to pass this value to server .. 
Note - I am giving example as pass it in url params, you can do as formdata or as json

```
 $.ajax({
 url: "urls_to_score_handler?score1=" + score1 , 
}).done(function()
 { alert('job dne'); });
```

Comment: Its giving me the undefined value,,,,,,,

Comment: i got this variable now how to store taht variable in database?

Comment: Here is steps, I am assuming you are using ajax call to pass this value to server ..

Note - I am giving example as pass it in url params, you can do as formdata or as json also 

$.ajax({
  url: "urls_to_score_handler?score1=" + score1 ,
}).done(function() {
  alert('job dne');
});

Comment: its not working,,,,,, is this correct
url: "/poll/score/?score1=" + score1 ,

Comment: what is not working ? ajax call or saving to server ?

Comment: Both
$.ajax({
        url: "/poll/score/",
        type: "post",
        data: "",
        
        success: function(response){          
            
            
        },
        error:function(){                  
        }
       });

Comment: What should i write in ajax call?

Answer (score 1):

Personaly, I would choose to use 2 html templates, even if they are identical.

However, in order to use the same html template for both of the views, make sure that the dictionaries you pass from the views have the same keys: at the miment they are different, one has 'questions' as a key entry, while the other has 'score1'.

Another solution would be to make if conditions inside the template: '{% if questions %}'' and '{% if score1 %}'

Comment: Hay how to use this if statement to templates?

Comment: made an edit...sorry, it is with `{%..%}`, instead of `{{....}}` . however, consider to really separate the logic inside your views, not inside your templates

Answer (score 0):

did you notice that you are assigning a Queryset into jQuery?
`score1=UserProfile.objects.all()` returns a Queryset, not even a single object and certainly no json that jQuery might understand.

Even an single django object would not be accepted by jQuery, because it does not understand django/python. You need to dump the single/multiple object first to json and then assign it in jQuery.

For [QuerySet-Serialization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/) see the docs.

I hope I could point you in the right direction.